# how to creat a Quad which is bent at midle point using QGLWidget or QGLBuilder?

Tags: qt, opengl

how to creat a Quad which is bent at midle point using QGLWidget or QGLBuilder?
actually i want to bend the quad i such a manner that can be looked like cutting of a sphere.

Answer (score 2):

> how to creat a Quad which is bent at midle point

You can't. A Quad is always flat by definition. You can of course tesselate the quad into a lot of small triangles and deform that mesh, but that's something different.

> QGLWidget or QGLBuilder?

Those don't matter.

Comment: thanx for your reply..can it  be possible to make logitudinal cut piece of a cylinder..using Opengl...that is what i want

Comment: @swarit: OpenGL is not a geometry library. OpenGL does exactly one thing: Draw points, lines and triangles. You can use various shaders to manipulate those. But something like a model, or a surface is completely outside the the scope of OpenGL.